# How to put an arrow indicator pointer on Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a ListView on my fragment which contains multiple items. What I need to do is put an arrow indicator (like this : ►) when one item is selected. I was able to put a border on the item chosen but the application requirement states that arrow (or any other symbol) is also needed to clearly show the current selected item. Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

put the arrow indicator in your item layout, and set the

```
android:visibility="GONE"
```

or

```
android:visibility="INVISIBLE"
```

in your getView() method, set the visibility of the arrow indicator based on wether the item is selected.
when item selection status changed, call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to refresh your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Set OnItemClickListener to your ListView. In onItemClick method you get the view which you have clicked. In this method you can findById your view with arrow indicator and set visibility to VISIBLE for show.(by default it hasGONE or INVISIBLE).

Of course you can create a view with arrow indicator and add it after clicked.